# What is the name of the “HAHA” SF Symbol?

Tags: font, icon

I’m looking for the “tapback” icons we get in Messages in SF Symbols:

[image: Tapback]

Some I can find the exact icon or an approximation:

- `heart.fill` is close.
- `hand.thumbsup.fill` seems to be the same.
- `hand.thumbsdown.fill` seems to be the same.
- `exclamationmark.2` isn’t great but works.
- `questionmark` isn’t great but works.

I haven’t found a good alternative for the HAHA symbol, though. Which is fine, there may not be one, *except* Apple features that very icon on their own [SF Symbols page](https://developer.apple.com/sf-symbols/):

[image: Symbols animations]

Which suggests that symbol should be part of SF Symbols, but I cannot find it in the SF Symbols 5 Beta.